# Apipie interferes with proper error codes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, http-headers

I can't seem to find this bit in Apipie's docs.

I have this RESTful api ready to go, and I thought I'd document it with Apipie. All fine and dandy, and param validation is nice, but I can't seem to make it throw the right HTTP code in response when validation fails. For example, I have this POST /users method which, obviously, creates a user in my database. Nice, right? Well, it responds with 422 Unprocessable entity if something's wrong, and that's fine, but then if, say, I throw at it parameters that do not pass apipie's validation, apipies chokes and throws a good old fashioned error, something along the lines of

```
Failure/Error: post '/users.json', :user => d
Apipie::ParamInvalid:
  Invalid parameter 'email' value "": Must match regular expression /[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]+\.[a-z]{2,}/.
# ./spec/requests/usersapi_spec.rb:66:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

assuming I have a regexp validation on the email parameter. Instead I would very much have liked it to respond nicely (possibly in json, or with empty body) and set the respose's code to 422.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: Yes, I know I can disable apipie's validation and do it otherwise...

Answer (score 13):

You can use a [rescue_from](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_from) and then respond with the error that makes sense for you.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  # ParamError is superclass of ParamMissing, ParamInvalid
  rescue_from Apipie::ParamError do |e|
    render text: e.message, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end

  # ...
end
```

Comment: I found this answer very useful and answers the question.

Answer (score 10):

Hope you already found the answer - but incase if anyone wants to disable the validations from Apipie - here it is.

```
Apipie.configure do |config|
  config.validate = false
end
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing, but it seems more like a workaround rather than a solution.

Comment: I guess the original idea is that you define your docs and then your api is held to the contract. this workaround is what I did too, since I prefer tests to be that contract.

Comment: Better than disabling validations, the answer from @carpeliam shows how to rescue from what would otherwise bubble up to a server exception.